# Trying to establish a simple closest approximation algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, openpyxl

I'm trying to create an algorithm in python that takes an input array (like the one mentioned below) and is able to store indices of numbers closest to every 300ms interval.

Example input:

> [0, 4.2, 12.3, 24.7, 33, 39.2, 47.7, 56.6, 68.3, 80.6, 90.8, 103,
> 109.8, 119.5, 129.8, 147.1, 155.3, 167, 173.8, 183.3, 190.4, 198.2, 207, 216.4, 224.3, 234.3, 244.7, 255.8, 262, 274, 286.2, 291.5,
> **300.8**, 306.6, 312.1, 324.3, 330.9, 336.5, 344.1, 350.6, 359, 369.3, 378, 387.5, 393.4, 402.8, 409.5, 416, 423.1, 433, 443, 451.1, 456.8, 469.4, 475.4, 486.8, 497.1, 508.6, 520.3, 532.5, 539.8, 548.4, 559.5, 571.6, 584.1, **593.3**, 601.3, 610.4, 620.9, 628.6, 639.6, 646.1, 651.5, 661.7, 676.1, 685.4, 696.7, 705.6, 717, 726.1, 731.8, 739, 745.3, 752.1, 759.9, 768.1, 779.9, 789, 806.5, 818.2, 830.4,
> 842.6, 848.9, 861.3, 867.3, 875.3, 881.8, 889.1, **897.8**, 903.7, 912.5, 919.9, 928.7, 938.3, 947.9, 958.1, 968.5, 973.9, 983.8, 993.9, 1004.2, 1015.1, 1021.3, 1028.4, 1037.8, 1047.8, 1053.4, 1061.5, 1069.9, 1081.9, 1094.1, 1100.5, 1109.5, 1121.7, 1127.6, 1133.4, 1142.1, 1147.6, 1155.4, 1163.4, 1174, 1183.9, 1190.6, **1198**, 1206.7, 1213.4, 1223, 1230.3, 1241.3, 1252.5, 1264.3, 1276.3, 1284.3, 1296.5, 1308.9, 1316.7, 1323.5, 1332.9, 1339.1, 1347.7, 1358.5, 1369.1, 1377.1, 1385.5, 1397.1, 1407.9, 1420, 1431.5, 1438.5, 1451, 1456.8, 1464.6, 1474.4, 1482.8, 1487.7, **1495.7**, 1506, 1517.8, 1526, 1536.1, 1542.9, 1548.9, 1555.4, 1566.2, 1577, 1589.1, 1600.1,
> 1609.1, 1617.2, 1628.5, 1640.3, 1649.9, 1660.3, 1670.5, 1681.1, 1692.1, 1703.3, 1709.3, 1721.1, 1730.9, 1740.8, 1753.8, 1761, 1769.6, 1777.3, 1783.9, **1794.3**, 1806.5]

My approach was to use an absolute value function to find the closest value and then up the interval each time. However, this will interfere with values like 0 (since abs(0-300) = 300 even though this answer is not correct. I have no idea what to do.

Here's what I kinda started with:

```
def check_num(prev, cur, iteration):
    MULTIPLE = 300
    num = MULTIPLE * iteration
    
    # returns true if current number is closer
    if abs(prev-num) > abs(cur-num):
        return True
    # returns false if current number is further
    elif abs(prev-num) < abs(cur-num):
        return False
    # if they are equal returns true still [edge case]
    else: return True

def arr_index_finder(arr):
    # define arr of indecies that work
    indexArr = []
    # initialize basic values
    prev = arr[0]
    curr = prev
    iteration = 1
    index = 0
    for el in arr:
        prev = curr
        curr = el
        index += 1
        if check_num(prev, curr, 1):
            # code for the alg
```

Comment: Surely 601.3 is closer than 593.3?

Comment: @Nick whoops. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, one approach is the calculate the `abs`, and keep track of the corresponding index in a tuple, then run `min` over the tuples.

```
l = [0, 4.2, 12.3, 24.7, 33, 39.2, 47.7, 56.6, ...] # ...'s for brevity
for m in [300,600,900,1200,1500,1800]:
    print(min((abs(m-i),idx) for idx, i in enumerate(l)))
```

This will give you the minimum value and the index, if you just want the index then replace the last line with;

```
     print(min((abs(m-i),idx) for idx, i in enumerate(l))[1])
```

This will be slow for very large lists, but there's scope to improve the time complexity if needed by restricting your search.

And finally, if you just want a list of the indices then the following list comprehension will calculate it;

```
[min((abs(m-i),idx) for idx, i in enumerate(l))[1] for m in [300,600,900,1200,1500,1800]]
```